# How to Fix SUM Calculation issue in html web forms

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

In my HTML  web application  form I have added some calculation function and logic is working perfectly fine however if I need to make some correction in already input filled tab other tab numbers are not getting updated until unless i dnot delete the entries of other fields

Example - updated some numbers in Unit Price, Quantity  and modify Unit Price again

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index').setTitle("Testing");
}


function getOAuthToken() {
  DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  Logger.log(ScriptApp.getOAuthToken())
  return ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();

}


function getCurrentUserEmail()
{
  var email={'email':Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()};//returned as an object
  return email;
}


function saveDate(data) {
    var openSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1fA5qPNfoegZoEpl1al3XudNEyvomgAbko5XDBA_i7aw").getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    var sheetHeader = openSpreadSheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, openSpreadSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    Logger.log(sheetHeader);
    var arrayToSave = [];
    data["Timestamp"] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date, "IST", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    data["Email Address"] = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail().toString();
    for (i = 0; i < sheetHeader.length; i++) {
        if (Object.keys(data).indexOf(sheetHeader[i]) != -1) {
            arrayToSave[i] = data[sheetHeader[i]];
        } else {
            arrayToSave[i] = "";
        }
    }       
    openSpreadSheet.appendRow(arrayToSave);
}

function include(fileName) {
  return HtmlService
  .createHtmlOutputFromFile(fileName)
  .getContent();
}

function initPicker() {
  return {
    locale: 'en',
    token: ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    origin: "https://script.google.com",
    parentFolder: "0B0Oj_1v-CAzNa2djbEQ1UjdzeDA",
    developerKey: "AIzaSyD9UvBsf_wdqxpTFgxzWhRtaI-VfITb_RY",
    dialogDimensions: {
      width: 600, 
      height: 425
    },
    picker: {
      viewMode: "LIST",
      mineOnly: true,
      mimeTypes: "image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg",
      multiselectEnabled: true,
      allowFolderSelect: true,
      navhidden: true,
      hideTitle: true,
      includeFolders: true,
    }
  };
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>123</title>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<!--Icons-->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

 <style>
  /*.form-group.num, .form-group.txt {
   margin-bottom:0; width:100px; display:block; clear:both; margin:0 auto}
   .form-group.txt { width:inherit;}*/
   th {    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e3f2fd;color:#263238 !important}
 tr.one th{   
    background-color: #f5f5f5;color:#263238 !important}
 
  
.navbar-brand {
  padding: 0px;
}
.navbar-brand>img {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  width: auto;
}
.navbar-default { background-color:#0a3474}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
    color: #0a3474;
    background-color: #FFF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
 color:#fff}
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover{
   color: #0a3474;
    background-color: #FFF;
  }
.gap10{
 height:10px; display:block; clear:both;}

th {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #009e16;
    color: #fff !important;}

  
  </style>


<style>

  #attachmentTable{ 
  background: white;
  }
  tr th,tr td{
  text-align: center;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href=""><img src="" alt="Dispute Bills">
        </a>
        
      </div>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> : <h9 id="email"></h9></a></li>
     
    </ul>
        </div>

  </nav>
  
  </div>
  
</div>


<hr>
<form name="newpurchase" action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:65%;margin:0 auto">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th  colspan="4">Procurement Request Form</th>
      
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Request Type </td>
        <td>
        <div class="form-group">
        <select name="supplier_name" class="form-control select" id="RequestType">
        <option value="Supply">Supply</option>
        <option value="Service">Service</option>
        <option value="Software">Software</option>
        
       </select></div></td>
        <td>Urgency</td>
        <td> <div class="form-group"><select name="supplier_name" class="form-control select"id="Urgency" >
        <option value="Low">Low</option>
        <option value="Medium">Medium</option>
        <option value="High">High</option>
        <option value="Critical">Critical</option>
        
       </select></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Requester For</td>
        <td> <div class="form-group"><select name="supplier_name" class="form-control select" id="RequestFor" >
        <option value="Cost for Approval">Cost for Approval</option>
        <option value="PO Process">PO Process</option>
        
       </select></div></td>
        <td>Currency</td>
        <td> <div class="form-group"><select name="payment_mode" id="select"  class="form-control select" >
        <option value="INR">INR</option>
        <option value="USD">USD</option>
       </select></div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Requester Name </td>
        <td>
<div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="contact_person" class="form-control input-md"  id="RequesterName"/></div></td>
        <td>Business User</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="contact_person" class="form-control input-md"  id="BusinessUser"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Short Description:</td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control input-md" id="ShortDescription" name="address_line2"></textarea></td>
        <td>Business Reason:</td>
        <td><textarea class="form-control input-md" id="BusinessReasonforRequestPurpose" name="address_line2"></textarea></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<hr>
<tr>
<div class="container">
  <td><table id="productList" class="table table-bordered">
    
      <tr>
        <th  colspan="9">Requested Material/Service Details-Cost</th>
      
      </tr>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr id="head"> 
        <td>SR No</td>
        <td>Product/Material/ServiceDescription</td>
        <td>Make & Model No</td>
        <td>UOM</td>
        <td>Unit Price</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total Price </td>
        <td>GST% </td>
        <td>Total Price with GST </td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
       <td  align="center">1</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription1"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo1"></div></td>
      <td> <div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM1" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input  class="form-control input-md price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice1"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input  class="form-control input-md qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY1"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price1"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST1" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input  class="form-control input-md total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice1"name="total"/></div></td>
                       
      </tr>
       <tr> 
 <td  align="center">2</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription2"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo2"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM2" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice2"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY2"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input    class="form-control input-md subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price2"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST2" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input  class="form-control input-md total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice2"name="total"/></div></td>
                       
      </tr>
       <tr> 
        <td  align="center">3</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription3"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo3"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM3" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice3"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY3"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price3"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST3" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice3"name="total"/></div></td>
                        
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td  align="center">4</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription4"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo4"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM4" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice4"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY4"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price4"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST4" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input   class="form-control input-md total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice4"name="total"/></div></td>
                       
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
       <td  align="center">5</td>  
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="purchase_description" type="text" id="ProductMaterialServiceDescription5"></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md" name="on_hand" type="text" id="MakeModelNo5"></div></td>
      <td width="120"><div class="form-group"><select class="form-control " name="productname" id="UOM5" >
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="">Nos</option>
        <option value="">Set</option>
        <option value="">LS</option>
                                <option value="">Per MDY</option>
        <option value="">Per Month</option>
        <option value="">Per Year</option>
       </select></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md price" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="UnitPrice5"name="price"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md qty" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="QTY5"name="qty"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md subtot" type="text" data-a-sign="%" data-p-sign="s" data-w-empty="zero" id="Price5"name="subtot"/></div></td>
      <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md gst" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="GST5" name="gst"/></div></td>
                        <td><div class="form-group"><input class="form-control input-md total" data-a-sign="` " data-w-empty="zero" type="text" id="TotalPrice5"name="total"/></div></td>
                        
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table></td>
</div></tr>


<!-- <body style='font-family: cursive;'> -->
  <script>google.load("picker", "1");</script>    
  <body style="margin:20px;">
    <div class="block form-group">
      <button onclick="openPicker()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Select Files</button>
      <button onclick="openUploader()" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Files</button>
      <div id="message"></div>
    </div>
   
 <hr>
 
 
  <div class="container">
          <div  class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5">
            <button style="width: 100%;" type="submit" id="updateBtn" class="btn btn-success" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>
          </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="input-field col s12" id = "progress">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div id="success" style="display:none">
        <p>Your Data  has been successfully uploaded.</p>
      </div>
<hr>

</body>


    <script>

function openPicker() {
  google.script.run
  .withFailureHandler(showMessage)
  .withSuccessHandler(showFilePicker)
  .initPicker();
}

function openUploader() {
  google.script.run
  .withFailureHandler(showMessage)
  .withSuccessHandler(showFileUploader)
  .initPicker();
}

function showFilePicker(config) {

  // Show all files in Google Drive for selection
  var view = new google.picker.DocsView(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
  
  view.setIncludeFolders(config.picker.includeFolders)
    .setSelectFolderEnabled(config.picker.allowFolderSelect)
    .setParent(config.parentFolder)
      
  // Show file as a grid or list (compact)
  if (config.picker.viewMode === "GRID") 
    view.setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.GRID);
  else
    view.setMode(google.picker.DocsViewMode.LIST);
  
  if (config.picker.mimeTypes) 
    view.setMimeTypes(config.picker.mimeTypes);
  
  var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
  .addView(view)
  .setLocale(config.locale)
  .setOAuthToken(config.token)
  .setDeveloperKey(config.developerKey)
  .setCallback(fileSelected)
  .setOrigin(config.origin)
  .setSize(config.dialogDimensions.width - 2,
           config.dialogDimensions.height - 2);
  
  if (config.picker.hideTitle) 
   picker.hideTitleBar();
   
  // Show files / folders owned by the user
  if (config.picker.mineOnly)
    picker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MINE_ONLY);
  
  if (config.picker.navhidden)
    picker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN);
  
  // Allow uses to select multiple files / folders
  if (config.picker.multiselectEnabled)
  picker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
  
  picker.build().setVisible(true);
  
}

function showFileUploader(config) {

  var upload = new google.picker.DocsUploadView()
  
  upload.setIncludeFolders(config.picker.allowFolderSelect)

  // allowFolderSelect and multiselectEnabled should be enabled
  // setting parent folder disables folder selection
  if (config.parentFolder) 
    upload.setParent(config.parentFolder);

  // Limit the user from uploading specific types
  if (config.picker.mimeTypes) 
    upload.setMimeTypes(config.picker.mimeTypes);
  
  var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
  .addView(upload)
  .setLocale(config.locale)
  .setOAuthToken(config.token)
  .setDeveloperKey(config.developerKey)
  .setCallback(fileSelected)
  .setOrigin(config.origin)
  .setSize(config.dialogDimensions.width - 2,
           config.dialogDimensions.height - 2);
  
  if (config.picker.hideTitle) 
   picker.hideTitleBar();
     
  if (config.picker.navhidden)
    picker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN);
  
  if (config.picker.multiselectEnabled)
    picker.enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
 
  picker.build().setVisible(true);
  
}

function fileSelected(data) {
  var html = [];
  var action = data[google.picker.Response.ACTION];
  if (action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
    var documents = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < documents.length ; i++) {
   html.push([
    documents[i][google.picker.Document.MIME_TYPE],
    documents[i][google.picker.Document.NAME],
    documents[i][google.picker.Document.URL]
    ].join("\t"));    
    }
  } else if (action == google.picker.Action.CANCEL) {
    html.push("No file selected");
  }
  showMessage(html.join("\n"));
}

function showMessage(message){
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = message;
   loger.log (message)
}

</script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
          $(function () {
            $('.pnm, .price, .subtot, .grdtot');
            var $tblrows = $("#productList tbody tr");

            $tblrows.each(function (index) {
                var $tblrow = $(this);

                $tblrow.find('.qty').on('change', function () {

                    var qty = $tblrow.find("[name=qty]").val();
                    var price = $tblrow.find("[name=price]").val();
                    var subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

                    if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

                        $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
                        var grandTotal = 0;

                        $(".subtot").each(function () {
                            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
                        });

                        $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
                    }
                });
            });
        });



var $price      = $("input[name='subtot']"),
    $percentage = $("input[name='gst']").on("input", calculatePrice),
    $total   = $("input[name='total']").on("input", calculatePerc);
    

function calculatePrice() {
    var percentage = $(this).val();
    var price = parseFloat($(this).closest('tr').find('.subtot').val());
    var calcPrice  = (price + ( price * percentage / 100 )).toFixed(2);
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.total').val(calcPrice);
}

function calculatePerc() {
    var total = $(this).val();
    var price    = $price.val();
    var calcPerc = 100 - (total * 100 / price);
    $percentage.val( calcPerc );
}

    </script>
    <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {

    google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(dispEmail)
      .getCurrentUserEmail();
     });//runs after dom is loaded
     function dispEmail(data)
     {
       $('#email').text(data.email);//put's email into h1 tag
     }
     console.log('My Code');    
     

        function submitForm(btnClicked) {
            $("button").attr("disabled", true);
            var jsonObj = {};
            jsonObj["Requester Name"] = $("#RequesterName").val();
            jsonObj["Business User"] = $("#BusinessUser").val();
            jsonObj["Request Type"] = $("#RequestType").val();
            jsonObj["Request For"] = $("#RequestFor").val();
            jsonObj["Short Description"] = $("#ShortDescription").val();
            jsonObj["Business Reason for Request/Purpose"] = $("#BusinessReasonforRequestPurpose").val();
            jsonObj["Urgency "] = $("#Urgency").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(1)"] = $("#SNo1").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(2)"] = $("#SNo2").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(3)"] = $("#SNo3").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(4)"] = $("#SNo4").val();
            jsonObj["S. No(5)"] = $("#SNo5").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(1)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription1").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(2)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription2").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(3)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription3").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(4)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription4").val();
            jsonObj["Product/Material/ServiceDescription(5)"] = $("#ProductMaterialServiceDescription5").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(1)"] = $("#MakeModelNo1").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(2)"] = $("#MakeModelNo2").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(3)"] = $("#MakeModelNo3").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(4)"] = $("#MakeModelNo4").val();
            jsonObj["Make &amp; Model No(5)"] = $("#MakeModelNo5").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(1)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(2)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(3)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(4)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["UOM(5)"] = $("#UOM1").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(1)"] = $("#QTY1").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(2)"] = $("#QTY2").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(3)"] = $("#QTY3").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(4)"] = $("#QTY4").val();
            jsonObj["QTY(5)"] = $("#QTY5").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(1)"] = $("#UnitPrice1").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(2)"] = $("#UnitPrice2").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(3)"] = $("#UnitPrice3").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(4)"] = $("#UnitPrice4").val();
            jsonObj["Unit Price(5)"] = $("#UnitPrice5").val();
            jsonObj["Price(1)"] = $("#Price1").val();
            jsonObj["Price(2)"] = $("#Price2").val();
            jsonObj["Price(3)"] = $("#Price3").val();
            jsonObj["Price(4)"] = $("#Price4").val();
            jsonObj["Price(5)"] = $("#Price5").val();
            jsonObj["GST(1)"] = $("#GST1").val();
            jsonObj["GST(2)"] = $("#GST2").val();
            jsonObj["GST(3)"] = $("#GST3").val();
            jsonObj["GST(4)"] = $("#GST4").val();
            jsonObj["GST(5)"] = $("#GST5").val();
            jsonObj["Total Price(1)"] = $("#TotalPrice1").val();
            jsonObj["Total Price(2)"] = $("#TotalPrice2").val();
            jsonObj["Total Price(3)"] = $("#TotalPrice3").val();
            jsonObj["Total Price(4)"] = $("#TotalPrice4").val();
            jsonObj["Total Price(5)"] = $("#TotalPrice5").val();
            jsonObj["Documents"] = $("#message").html();
            jsonObj["updateBtn"] = $(btnClicked).text();
            google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(afterSaving).saveDate(jsonObj);
            return false;
        }

        function afterSaving() {
            alert("Thanks, Your response has been recorded");
            $("button").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    </script>
```

you dnot delete the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `price` class along with `qty` class and change the event listener to `keyup`. Refer the below snippet.

```
$tblrow.find('.qty, .price').on('keyup', function() {
    var qty = $tblrow.find("[name=qty]").val();
    var price = $tblrow.find("[name=price]").val();
    var subTotal = parseInt(qty, 10) * parseFloat(price);

    if (!isNaN(subTotal)) {

        $tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toFixed(2));
        var grandTotal = 0;

        $(".subtot").each(function() {
            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
            grandTotal += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
        });

        $('.grdtot').val(grandTotal.toFixed(2));
    } else {
        $tblrow.find('.subtot').val("");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, Riz, One more help how to add .toLocaleString to genrate numbers in Indian format

Comment: Just add  `$tblrow.find('.subtot').val(subTotal.toLocaleString('en-IN'));`

Comment: Riz, After adding above lines script stopped working can you please review

Comment: which part of the script?

Comment: calculation function is not working - means Outbupts are not getting generated in "Total Price Box"